# Python if statement always printing incorrect

Tags: python, if-statement

I was trying to make a algebra program but even if i type the correct answer, it prints incorrect

```
x= random.randrange(1, 100)
x2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
answer = input('if x + ' + str(x2) + ' = ' + str(x + x2) + ' what is x equal to? ')
ranswer = x + x2
if answer == ranswer:
   print('correct')
else:
   print('incorrect')
```

NVM GUYS I WAS JUST STUPID
shouldve done ranswer = x 
:P

Comment: This will never be true. When will one number be equal to itself plus another number unless that other number is zero? That is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

```
x= random.randrange(1, 100)
x2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
answer = input('if x + ' + str(x2) + ' = ' + str(x + x2) + ' what is x equal to? ')
if int(answer) == x:
   print('correct')
else:
   print('incorrect')
```

As Malik says, you had a problem in your logic. I fixed that, and cast the `answer` variable to an integer so it would compare properly.

Comment: doesnt work either. ive tried all int(answer) == ranswer
int(answer) == int(ranaswer), str(answer) == str(ranswer) but none works

Comment: @Brian010515 what version of Python are you using? This code worked for me on 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Monitor your code (python 2.7)

```
#exam_plus.py 
import random

x= random.randrange(1, 100)
x2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
answer = raw_input('if x + ' + str(x2) + ' = ' + str(x + x2) + ' what is x equal to? ')
ranswer = x + x2
print "answer", answer
print "correct answer", ranswer #it is obviously not correct, i just put it to show what your program expects

if int(answer) == ranswer:
   print'correct'
else:
   print 'incorrect'
```

run it

```
$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 52 = 55 what is x equal to? 3
answer 3
correct answer 55
incorrect

$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 81 = 88 what is x equal to? 7
answer 7
correct answer 88
incorrect

$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 3 = 71 what is x equal to? 68
answer 68
correct answer 71
incorrect
```

that means your problems logic is incorrect - you should edit `ranswer=x` which will result

```
$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 12 = 72 what is x equal to? 60
answer 60
correct answer 60
correct

$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 24 = 61 what is x equal to? 37
answer 37
correct answer 37
correct

$ python exam_plus.py 
if x + 88 = 151 what is x equal to? 63
answer 63
correct answer 63
correct
```